# Reducing the size of node labels in Latex

Tags: latex, tikz

I have the following code. I am trying to reduce the size of the side labels to match the labels inside the node (I do not want to increase the size of the inner labels). Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    > = stealth, % arrow head style
    shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
    auto,
    node distance = 2cm, % distance between nodes
    thick, dashed pattern=on % line style
    ]
    \tikzset{every state}=[
    draw = black,
    thick,
    fill = white,
    minimum size = 1mm
    ]


    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, label=right:$2$,scale=0.75] (4) at (0,0) {4};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, label=right:$5.75$, scale=0.75] (3) at (3,0.75) {3};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, label=right:$4.25$,scale=0.75] (2) at (2,4) {2};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, label=above:$7.75$,scale=0.75] (1) at (0,4) {1};

    \path [->] (1) edge node[left] {} (2);
    \path [->](2) edge node[left] {} (1);
    \path [->,draw, dotted, color=red](1) edge node[left] {} (4);
    \path [->,draw, dotted, color=red](4) edge node[left] {} (2);
    \path [->,draw, dotted, color=red](2) edge node[right] {} (3);
    \path [->,draw, dotted, color=red](3) edge node[left] {} (1);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: This is what I get]

Comment: `{\small 4}` instead of `{4}`...etc. helps? Sorry but I'm on mobile and I can't compile now :(

Comment: Does [this TeX SE post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304025/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-label-of-node-uniformly-in-tikz) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
[
    > = stealth, % arrow head style
    shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
    auto,
    node distance = 2cm, % distance between nodes
    thick, dashed pattern=on % line style
    ]

    \tikzset{every state}=[
    draw = black,
    thick,
    fill = white,
    minimum size = 1mm
    ]
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,label=right:$2$] (4) at (0,0) {4};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, label=right:$5.75$] (3) at (4.5,1.125) {3};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, label=right:$4.25$] (2) at (3,6) {2};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black, label=above:$7.75$] (1) at (0,6) {1};


  \path [->] (1) edge node[left] {} (2);
    \path [->](2) edge node[left] {} (1);
    \path [->,draw, dotted, color=red](1) edge node[left] {} (4);
    \path [->,draw, dotted, color=red](4) edge node[left] {} (2);
    \path [->,draw, dotted, color=red](2) edge node[right] {} (3);
    \path [->,draw, dotted, color=red](3) edge node[left] {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```